# pulse generator MATLAB

Tags: matlab, simulink

How to create a rectangular waveform with amplitude 18 to -3 using pulse generator? If I put 18 as the amplitude then the wave is between 18 and 0. How do I change that to 18 to -3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the amplitude 21 volts and subtract 3 volts DC from the pulse output.